# Артефакты в окне редактора vba

Tags: vba

В окне редактора vba  стали появляться артефакты. 
В место

```
Sub Report()
Dim os4 As New Excel.Application
Dim wBookOs4 As Workbook
Dim sheetOs4 As Worksheet
Dim act As Object
Dim dataIn As Date
Dim dataOut As Date
countList = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
iPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
i = 7
```

отображается

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/xyres.png

Comment: может потому, что обновились на последнюю винду?

К тому же, в вопросе совсем не понятно, каким редактором/иде пользуетесь (visual studio, встроенным в офис или самопальным). По шрифтам угадать сложно.

Как ещё один из вариантов - видеодрайвера.

Comment: windows 7 32bit. Редактор встроенный в мс офис

Comment: теперь нужно подумать, после чего это могло произойти.

 - проверить шрифт в настройках редактора.
 - вспомнить, не устанавливались последнее время какие-нибудь программы (пусть даже блокнотозаменители и украшатели кнопки пуск)

 и перейти на [биткод](http://user.hashcode.ru/) :)

Comment: Если не вирус, то, возможно, оперативная память глючит

Comment: Современные операционные системы достаточно сложные. И если бы это была оперативная память, проблема проявилась гораздо раньше. Самый простой способ ее протестировать - запустить любую игру, которая займет максимум памяти.